# WIX Installation Condition

Tags: windows, wix, office365

I have very specific condition to set for the WIX installer and every attempt so far failed.

I need to detect

- if Windows 10 is updated with Anniversary Edition Update
- if Office 365 version build 12.0.6965.2092 version is installed

RegistrySearch will give values to corresponding Properties but Condition is triggered no matter if the actual conditions are met or not.

```
<Property Id="OFFICE365DETECT">
    <RegistrySearch Id="Office365Search" Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\ClickToRun\Configuration" Name="ProductReleaseIds" Type="raw"/>
  </Property>
<Property Id="OFFICE365VERSIONDETECT">
  <RegistrySearch Id="Office365VersionSearch" Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\ClickToRun\Configuration" Name="ClientVersionToReport" Type="raw" />
</Property>
<!--Windows Anniversary Edition corresponds to CurentBuildNumber 14000 and above-->
<Property Id="WINDOWSANNIVERSARYEDITIONDETECT">
  <RegistrySearch Id="WindowsAnniversarySearch" Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion" Name="CurrentBuildNumber" Type="raw"/>
</Property>
```

Condition check supposed to look different, I know, but I couldn't find any guide for this very specific case.

```
    <![CDATA[((OFFICE365DETECT = "O365ProPlusRetail" OR OFFICE365DETECT = "O365BusinessRetail" OR OFFICE365DETECT = "O365SmallBusPremRetail" ) AND OFFICE365VERSIONDETECT = "16.0.6965.2092" AND WINDOWSANNIVERSARYEDITIONDETECT = "14393")]]>
```

I would greatly appretiate any suggestions, comments and critics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to search the registry for the Windows build number - there's a property WindowsBuild that you can use in the Launch Condition:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372813(v=vs.85).aspx

The documentation isn't up to date but I believe the value for the Anniversary Edition is 9600. It's more normal to say that you want <= 9600 if W10 Anniversary is the minimum you support, otherwise your setup will not install on later versions of Windows 10.

The Office search - the obvious thing to do is to look in the registry, and I assume you've already seen that the value is there. However your search may need to be in the 64-bit registry (use Win64="yes"). You haven't said what your architecture is and it may be defaulting to the wrong one for the search, described in the WiX documentation.

Comment: MSI installers running on Windows 10 1909 will also result in WindowsBuild 9600. I therefore am unsure if you can use this property to determine between Win10 versions.